# .Net Core 2.0 publish, dependency missing

Tags: publish, archlinux-arm, .net-core-2.0

I have the same hello world project (which is what you create from the template) on 2 separate computers, one was created and copied to the other pc. Both have .net core 2.0, and I'm using command line to build: "dotnet publish -r linux-arm".

For a while it worked on both, but one of them stops on console.writeline with the exeption that it doesn't find System.Runtime.Extensions. And for that build it's not there in the folder (the dll), also not referenced in the "ConsoleApp1.deps.json", that's the only difference between the 2 builds, but the source is 100% the same.

I even tried removing all .net core installations from that pc, and vs2017 preview and reinstalling .net core 2.0 (tried it right after uninstallation and it didn't recognize the dotnet command)

If I replace the dependency file and add that dll to the failing build, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete "c:\Users{User}.nuget\packages", then "dotnet restore", afterwards the build ran fine